# Retrieving only firstname and surname of persons in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Hi I am newbie in using DBpedia and SPARQL. I want to retrieve firstname and lastname of all Norwegian persons that are stored on DBpedia like below:

```
Henrik Ibsen
Iver Fossum
etc.
```

Here is my query:

```
PREFIX      dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbpedia:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?person 
WHERE
{ ?person  dbo:birthPlace  dbpedia:Norway 
}
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What is your query doing, and why isn't it what you want or expect? Where, exactly, are you stuck with getting to your goal? Have a look at [ask] for some tips on how to ask answerable questions here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using SPARQL to explore the properties.  Try the following to find which properties are most useful for your purposes:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?person ?p ?o
WHERE{
   ?person dbo:birthPlace dbpedia:Norway .
   ?person ?p ?o .
   FILTER isLiteral(?o)
}
```

The `FILTER` is optional and used here to eliminate all of the type triples, etc. that probably aren't useful for this query.

Comment: your solution does not not respond to my question :(

Comment: The idea is to guide you to the solution, such that you also learn how to do things. If you follow Scott's suggestion, you will see that there are not for all persons properties for firstname and lastname - but sometimes there are `foaf:givenName` and `foaf:surname`. Now it's up to you to extend your query and show that you understood how to use SPARQL on unknown datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbpedia:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT distinct ?firstname ?lastname WHERE {

?person dbo:birthPlace dbpedia:Norway .
?person foaf:givenName ?firstname .
?person foaf:surname ?lastname .

}
```